# How to use a self join on this table instead of the subquery being used when a concatenation is taking place?

Tags: mysql, db2, subquery, resultset

I have the following query

```
Select DISTINCT a.code,a.Code_group,a.value,a.code_auth FROM AEO.CODE_CM a WHERE a.CODE_GROUP IN 
(SELECT CONCAT (b.code,'_PART') FROM AEO.CODE_CM b WHERE b.CODE_GROUP ='EPE_AUTHTYPE');
```

So based on the code_group value it receives it picks each code and concatenates the string to it and returns it as a code_group. I need to avoid using subquery to make it less complex and since its the same table I tried to use self join as

```
Select DISTINCT a.code,a.Code_group,a.value,a.code_auth FROM AEO.CODE_CM a INNER JOIN  AEO.CODE_CM b 
ON a.code_group =b.code_group WHERE a.code_group = CONCAT(b.code,'_PART') AND b.code_group ='EPE_AUTHTYPE';
```

But I am getting a blank result in this case

Comment: Do you really use IBM [tag:db2] ? If not please remove that tag.

Comment: For what it's worth, your subquery is not a *dependent subquery* so it will perform quite well. If you recast this query as a JOIN, it may very well come out harder to read and harder to reason about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queries are not equivalent, since you have wrong additional `a.code_group = b.code_group` predicate in the 2-nd query.
It should be something like this:

```
WITH AEO_CODE_CM (CODE, CODE_GROUP) AS
(
VALUES 
  ('code1', 'EPE_AUTHTYPE')
, ('code2', 'code1_PART')
)

Select DISTINCT a.code, a.Code_group 
FROM AEO_CODE_CM a
/* 
WHERE a.CODE_GROUP IN 
(
SELECT CONCAT (b.code,'_PART') 
FROM AEO_CODE_CM b 
WHERE b.CODE_GROUP ='EPE_AUTHTYPE'
)
*/
--/*
JOIN AEO_CODE_CM b ON a.code_group = CONCAT(b.code,'_PART') 
WHERE b.code_group ='EPE_AUTHTYPE'
--*/
;
```

Comment: @amitsingh6651 Please, mark the answer as accepted then.

Comment: Just a Question Mark, can a OR be applied on the column a.code_group after the WHERE b.code_group ='EPE_AUTHTYPE'? Means the OR applied on the same column on basis of which join is applied? Like WHERE b.CODE_GROUP ='EPE_AUTHTYPE' OR a.CODE_GROUP = 'EPE_AUTHTYPE' ? because I used and it shows a different result set

Comment: You can't just add arbitrary condition to one of the equivalent sql statements and complain, that the results are different. A better way is to provide some sample data, the result needed, and some logical description of what you want to achieve.

Comment: select distinct a.code, a.Code_group from AEO.CODE_CM  a WHERE a.code_group IN (select concat (b.code,'_PART') from AEO.CODE_CM b where b.code_group ='EPE_AUTHTYPE') OR a.code_group = 'EPE_AUTHTYPE';                                        so basically the a.code_group should return a resultset consisting of _PART type results as well as  'EPE_AUTHTYPE results. I had forgotten to add the external OR a.code_group =' EPE_AUTHTYPE' after subquery. The Join is required for the entire query.